# Wired USB connected foldable keyboard with mouse?

Tags: usb, keyboards, mice, portable

I am looking for a computer keyboard with the following three properties:

1. It is foldable (not the soft silicon rolling type keyboards, but hard material with folding joints) or extra-small,
2. It can be connected wired with USB (or PS/2, there are adapters. Wireless is optional nice feature, but must not be the only way),
3. It has an integrated mouse (trackpoint preferred, but other types also accepted).

I did a lot of search using the internet and some online stores, and only find keyboards which fullfill two of the three criteria, but not all three in one device.

Is there any device which fullfills the three criteria? Which?

Answer (score -1):

I believe [iClever IC-BK08](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MTVC775) would do the job. [Here](http://www.notebookreview.com/review/iclever-ic-bk08-portable-tri-folding-bluetooth-keyboard-touchpad-review/) is a review. It has a micro-USB port but there are adapters.

Comment: I also did find this in my researches. BUT: Can it communicate via the micro USB? Or is it only for charging? Everywhere it is only stated as "wireless", and to be charged via micro USB. Also the mentioned review says nothing about communication via USB.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by communicating?

Comment: @IgorTheBoss, sending keypress and mouse signals over the USB cable.  As stated in the Amazon Q&A, this keyboard is Bluetooth-only, using the USB cable for charging.

Comment: Oh no it can't do that, but it seems thats the only one I could find that fits almost all of your requests

Comment: @IgorTheBoss, I did a similar search about two years ago, and found plenty that fit *almost* all the requirements.  I found zero that fit all three.