# Small (pocket size) folding wired USB keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboards, portable

I'm looking for a small wired keyboard that could be used with a mobile phone (capable of [USB OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go)).

Requirements:

1. USB connection, preferably microUSB connector (to remove the need for reductions)
2. foldable (e.g. like [HB066](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0GA-00UX-00003))
3. preferably *without* wireless capabilities
4. may include touchpad
5. may need batteries

The question is similar to [Wired USB connected foldable keyboard with mouse?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/wired-usb-connected-foldable-keyboard-with-mouse), apart from the requirement to include touch area.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

[**Foldable Keyboard, Jelly Comb B003S 3-in-1 (USB/Microusb/Type C) Wired & BT Keyboard with Touchpad Compatible for All Devices Windows PC iOS Android Tablet-Black**](https://amzn.to/2RO18uk)

Seems to match everything (but does include Bluetooth as well.)

Answer (score 0):

[iClever BK05](https://www.iclever.com/products/BK05-Tri-Folding-Bluetooth-Keyboard) fits my bill for now. It does have Bluetooth, but is also able to work via USB.